# computer cables

Tags: cables

I'm trying to build a built-in computer cabinet.  I want to route the surge protector cord and cables through the cabinet floor to the front of the 2x6 base. The electrical outlet is on the adjacent wall about 6 ft away. Is there a hose or anything on the market to pass the cables through the dead space under the cabinet?  Maybe to attach to a desk grommet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some flexible nonmetallic conduit in there - you won't be using it as an actual conduit, just as a sleeve to route the cable.  The one in the picture is Carlon Resi-guard but there are many other brands.

[image: Carlon Resi-Guard]

It's sold in home improvement stores along with straps, fittings, boxes, etc. to make a nice install.

You're in a gray area with the electrical code, depending on whether this cabinet is a piece of furniture or a fixed part of the building.  Running flexible cords through the walls, floors, ceilings etc. is not permitted.  But it's certainly safer in a sleeve that prevents the cord from getting pinched or damaged.

Answer (score 1):

As batsplatsterson indicated there are products made specifically for networking cables.  I'm familiar rigid and flexible blue ones - the rigid ones have special connectors.

If you run the lines through plastic cable, however, I would separate the computer, TV & TV audio cabling from the electrical cables. You should not mix powered wiring with non-powered or low voltage wiring to prevent an electrical shock or worse.